# undefined reference to `USER_ERROR__inconsistent_build_configuration__see_dlib_faq_1_'

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, centos, dlib

So when I use the command `make` I get the following error:

```
[jalal@goku c++]$ make
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/TestSVM.dir/TestSVM.cpp.o
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable TestSVM
CMakeFiles/TestSVM.dir/TestSVM.cpp.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
TestSVM.cpp:(.text+0x28c3): undefined reference to `USER_ERROR__inconsistent_build_configuration__see_dlib_faq_1_'
TestSVM.cpp:(.text+0x28cf): undefined reference to `USER_ERROR__inconsistent_build_configuration__see_dlib_faq_2'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [TestSVM] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/TestSVM.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The files look like:

```
[jalal@goku c++]$ ls
CMakeCache.txt  CMakeFiles  CMakeLists.txt  Makefile  TestSVM.cpp  TrainSVM.cpp  cmake_install.cmake  json.hpp  trained_svms
```

I built the `dlib` in `/scratch2/dlib` from source using this repo:https://github.com/davisking/dlib
by following these commands:

```
mkdir build; cd build; cmake .. -DUSE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS=1; cmake --build .
```

I am not sure how I should fix this problem.
I followed the following commands in the git repo I cloned:

```
$ cd c++
$ cmake .
$ make
```

https://github.com/sausax/pose_estimation

Additionally not sure how to make sense out of this for fixing the bug

https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/dlib/test_for_odr_violations.cpp

Comment: The identifier is obviously crafted as a hint in the error message. Did you actually try to "see dlib FAQ 1"?

Comment: I did actually saw it as it was the first thing shows in googling it! But how to fixed it based on it?

Comment: Your `dlib` building command sequence does not seem to contain a `make install` or equivalent (per [dlib FAQ 2](http://dlib.net/faq.html#WhydoIgetUSERERRORinconsistentbuildconfigurationseedlibfaq2)). Did you skip that step?

Comment: there was not any "make install" in the git repo of dlib. I did a make install now and no difference!

Comment: You need to link to dlib.  There are instructions here: http://dlib.net/compile.html

Comment: there is no make install in the github repo README!

Answer (score 0):

As the commenter said, don't forget to link to dlib!  You can do this in CMake with:

```
target_link_libraries(<YOUR APP> dlib::dlib)
```

I wasn't able to get plain `dlib` to link, but I tried `${dlib_LIBRARIES}` and finally CMake clued me in with:

```
CMake Warning at lib/cmake/dlib/dlibConfig.cmake:42 (message):
  The variable 'dlib_LIBRARIES' is deprecated! Instead, simply use
  target_link_libraries(your_app dlib::dlib).  See
  http://dlib.net/examples/CMakeLists.txt.html for an example.
```

I too was distracted by the `ENABLE_ASSERTS` pointing to the FAQ, but that was due to me having the includes without the linked library.